# Unable to auto resize datagridview rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on DataGridView and trying to make it resize rows automatically so that contents fit.
I've tried setting property **AutoSizeRowsMode** of datagridview to **AllCell**s and setting property **WrapMode** to **True**
Currently,most of the time, the rows do resize automatically and contents can be fully shown.
However,**sometimes some rows'height is still shorter than what is needed to make contents fully shown**.
You can see this in the picture below:
[image]

I've searched the Internet and still can't find a way to figure this issue out.
Could you pleeeeeease tell me if there is a way to fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: *The content isn't fully shown*: `WrapMode` performs word wrapping. If the FormattedValue doesn't contain spaces, it's not wrapped. Would you like the grid to wrap formatted numbers? - *More text should have been shown*: clarify, what text would you like to see there? -- Most classes in this namespace that are not marked as `sealed`, are explicitly designed for inheritance. Some Properties and methods are marked as `protected` in this class, you need to override them to generate custom behavior, as an overload of the `AutoResizeRows()` / `AutoResizeRow()` methods

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for replying me."what text would you like to see there?": That column is used to show the paths of the files.And as you can see in the picture,only a part of the paths was shown.The rest text of those paths remains invisible since the height of the rows is not enough for the rest to be shown.However, most of the time, such issue doesn't occur.And I do think there are spaces in those paths.I have no idea what caused this.